# How to smooth images corner and merge background color?

Tags: photoshop

[image]

Please see the above image. how to smooth imgaes corner and merge background color together? I searched some documents for smoothing corners said using feather and delete reversal corner. But I didn't get enough result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** choose a background color that can easily blend with the image, so that when you try to merge the image with background it should not look different.

**Secondly**, I prefer to use  LAYER MASKING over FEATHER for merging image with background.
Layer Masking gives you more better options to make the edges blend more clear and merged.

You can see how to use Layer Masking in Adobe Photoshop with following links.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/photoshop-fade-layer-mask/

Comment: You were previously warned about this, but do not use signatures or taglines in your posts, particularly ones that advertise your company. If this continues, we will suspend your account.